# Call method in new thread and assign returned value to variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to call a method as a new thread, as well as assigning the value returned by the method to a variable.

EG:

```
int numObjects = thread t7(methodName(parameter));
```

How do I go about doing this?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but this has stumped me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) in combination with [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

```
std::future<int> fut = std::async(methondname, parameter);

// do something

// will wait for the result to become available
std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;
```

I can also recommend to read the `std::async` docs I linked to as there are different launch policies, e.g.: does it really run in a seperate thread or is it executed lazyly.

Another possibility would be to simply use output parameters(via `std::ref`) with `std::thread`, then however you would have to manually join and also don't get the exception safety that is inherit to `std::async`. So you better stick to `std::async`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the solution looks good.
However, the line
    `std::future<int> fut = std::async(detectAndDisplayInt, frame);`
creates the error "conversion from ‘std::future<bool>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::future<int>’ requested"

Do you know what needs changing?

Comment: @jgreen are you sure that `detectAndDisplayInt` returns an int and no bool?

Comment: @baboon
My mistake, I was in an old version of my code by accident!
You are correct, as is your solution. Thank you very much for your time.